# removing last item of list nav border

Tags: html, css

im struggling to remove the "pipe" border i have on the last item of the nav list- my code-

```
<div id="header">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Stories</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Tell your story</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Prizes</a></li>
        <li><a href="">How to tips</a></li>
    </li>
</div>
```

And my css

```
#menu li{
    float:left;
    list-style-type: none;
    display:inline;
    padding:0 .9em;
    border-right:1px solid #d2d2d2;;
}
#menu li.last{
    border-right:none;
}
```

Comment: Your markup is incorrect - you have an additional `</li>` instead of a `</ul>`.

Comment: Obviously you have your class `.last` not in your HTML code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

li.last doesn't excists. If you want to do it like that you'll have to add a class property to the last list item:

```
<div id="header">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Stories</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Tell your story</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Prizes</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="">How to tips</a></li>
    </li>
</div>
```

And the css

```
#menu li{
    float:left;
    list-style-type: none;
    display:inline;
    padding:0 .9em;
    border-right:1px solid #d2d2d2;;
}
#menu li.last{
    border-right:none;
}
```

Comment: It _is_ `li.last`, because the border is applied to the `li`, not the `a`

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) to only set a left border for those `li` elements that have a preceding `li` sibling:

```
#menu li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 .9em;
}
#menu li + li {
    border-left: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For all browsers, add the class to the last list item:

```
<div id="header">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Stories</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Tell your story</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Prizes</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="">How to tips</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Or, easier, for newer browsers, use the last-child pseudo-selector:

```
#menu li:last-child {
    border-right:none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
.menu ul li.last{border-right:none;}
```

Use this code works good .