# Show / hide toggle Magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: jquery, magento, toggle, hide, show

I have made a show/hide toggle on JSfiddle, but when I'll put the files on my Magento installation, everything is visible. Why is not it working?

I have put the HTML files in a CMS page, the CSS files in local.css and the javascript in a new document, called click.js. I have put all the files in my theme folder.

Here is de link:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/h2j6zx06/2/
```

```js
    $('.boxclick').hide();

    $('.clickme').each(function () {
        $(this).show(0).on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $(this).next('.boxclick').slideToggle('fast');
            $(this).toggleClass('close');
        });
    });
```

```css
.clickme {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top: 1px dashed #ccc;
    color: #555;
    background: url('../images//faq-closed.png') no-repeat 10px center;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 10px 15px 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.clickme:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.boxclick {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
    padding: 0px 10px 15px 50px;
    width: auto;
}
.clickme.close {
    background: url('../images/faq-open.png') no-repeat 10px center;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="clickme">Click Me</a>

<div class="boxclick">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
<a href="#" class="clickme">Click Me</a>

<div class="boxclick">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to add the javascript inside the cms page you're using.

Otherwise you'll have to inform Magento that there's a new javascript file present to be used and attach it within head.html or in page.xml in your theme's folder.

I'd also flush cache. Just in case :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still not working. I used: 

<script>   
$('.boxclick').hide();

    $('.clickme').each(function () {
        $(this).show(0).on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $(this).next('.boxclick').slideToggle('fast');
            $(this).toggleClass('close');
        });
    });

</script>

and flushed cache, but there is still no hide/show function.

Comment: Also... Magento by default uses prototype so if you're using  jQuery you'll need to assign it to a different variable/wrap it and use noConflict if you want to use both libraries side by side. Find this file in the them you're using: \template\page\html\head.phtml and add this line to it: <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/change-me-to-latest-version"></script> You will then be able to call jQuery using jQuery.

Comment: I have add the line you've written down in "head.phtml" and it is still not working... Hope you have another solution?

Comment: Check if jquery is loading in the page source. If its not you may need to check your template/block hints and ensure the head.phtml you modified is the one that the website is using.

Comment: How do I do that? It is all pretty new for me. In you last answer, I only add the javascript in head.phtml. Was that enough or should I also change something else in that file?

Comment: Right click on the web page and view source. If the jquery you added shows up you have another issues while using it. Also go to your admin panel -> System -> Configuration ->Developer (at the bottom left) and select show template hints/blocks to yes. This will render template/blocks sources on the page. Ensure that the head.phtml you edited matches the path displayed in head.phtml that shows up in template hints.

Comment: The jquery shows up in "head", if I click on " Inspect element". After I set the hints/blocks to yes, I saw all the blocks on my screen on the front end. I put the Jquery code in different templates, but it is still not working...

Comment: Wrap your JavaScript in document ready. Double check if your custom JavaScript function is coming through on the front end when you view source.

Comment: I think that the code I made, is not set up correctly. Because when I put all the files from http://jsfiddle.net/h2j6zx06/2/ to http://codepen.io/pen/, then you see what I also have on my site. (Not clickable) When I look at my product page and click on " inspect element"  on the product tab, I see there is a jQuery v1.8.2 jquery.com. For the product tabs it is working. Do you see what mistake I made in the code on jsfiddle?

Comment: I found a new code and customized it a bit. It is working now! Thanks for you help! Another question... Do you know how I can give the last toggle/dropdown a border-bottom? So only the last one should have a border-bottom. This is my new code: http://jsfiddle.net/m2601dvx/

Comment: Generally those are given a specific class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112729/removing-last-item-of-list-nav-border

Comment: I tried it, but I think that I am doing something wrong. Because when I open the last toggle, you should see the border below the "answer"  and not below the "question". If the last question is closed, than you should see the border below the question.